# Use one login for multiple apps

Tags: java, web-services, rest, authentication, alfresco

We have two running apps Odoo and Alfresco. We want the user first to login in Odoo then the Odoo server will post data to Alfresco through the REST API. So far we can achive this by resending username/password from Odoo to Alfresco, but as you can see this is not the appropriate way to do it. Is There a way to avoid the reuse of username/password for a server to server connction ?

Comment: Have you looked into single sign on (SSO) standards like SAML or OAUTH? The user authenticates then a token is used for Authorization into app services.

Comment: Acutally am looking for something like OAuth. Unfortunatly i'm unable to set Alfresco as a Service porvider

Comment: Is that from a lack of support on Alfresco side?

Comment: Yes i couldn't find a support for it.

Comment: Assuming I am getting the right product there is a wiki for it here https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/SSO

Comment: Alfresco Cloud supports OAuth 2.0 (see http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/pra/1/concepts/pra-authentication-cloud.html) but not on-premise - however, given that the implementation exists it might be possible to request that this is support is integrated into Enterprise/Community in a future release - I appreciate that this doesn't solve your problem immediately, but unless Alfresco are made aware of these requirements then they will not be implemented.

Comment: I've successfully used CAS for this kind of integration. Once configured, you can use a proxy ticket to communicate with Alfresco transparently from Odoo (in theory, I've done this with other Java based applications such as Liferay).